# Why are we using kill -9 always

Tags: kill, signals

I would like to know the kill stages. We always use `kill -9` and not any other numbers. Can anyone explain the reason.

Comment: How can we explain your reasons?

Comment: I'm not amongst the "we". You shouldn't blindingly use "kill -9" first.

Comment: `kill -9` is numeric shorthand for `kill -KILL`: use `kill` to send the `SIGKILL` signal.  On many systems you can use `kill -l` to list available signals.

Comment: Don't use `kill -9`. Start with just `kill`.

Comment: There is a theory that says if a prog can not be killed by `kill -15` which is the normal way to terminate normally a prog, then remove this prog since it misbehaves and does not follow the common programming rules and potentially might misbehave in other cases also.

Comment: Related: [When should I not kill -9 a process?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/8916)

Answer (score 15):

Actually, I quite like Bob's answer.

The signals I use are:

- `-1` (`-HUP`) - restart a process
- `-2` (`-INT`) - terminate a process
- `-9` (`-KILL`) - let the kernel kick the process out
- `-11` (`-SEGV`) - have the program crash brutally
- `-15` (`-TERM`) - the default, ask the program kindly to terminate.

Kill without signal will send `-15` (`-TERM`).

All the above signal names can be specified the `SIG` prefix (e.g. `-SIGKILL`), this, however, is optional.

Note, `kill -11` will force the program to exit with a segmentation fault, I use it sometimes, when `kill -9` won't terminate a process. (You might lose data if you issue `kill -9` or `kill -11` on a process, so beware!)

You use `ps -ef | grep <program>` to inspect the process. To get rid of a  process (which has parent PID 1), you have to `kill -HUP 1` or `kill -1 1` (both as root). Note that PID 1 is your [init system](https://felipec.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/init/).

So, to terminate a process, issue `kill <pid>` (the exact same as `kill -15 <pid>`), if that fails I try these others (you could lose data!), `kill -2 <pid>` (akin to doing `Ctrl+c`), if that fails `kill -9 <pid>`, if that fails `kill -11 <pid>`, if that fails the process is most likely a zombie process, ensure that is the case using `ps -ef | grep <program_name>` or `ps -ef | grep <pid>`, it should mention "defunct" after the process. This is when you issue `kill -1 1`.

Some programs, such as Java JVM's, can be configured to dump threads/heap (for troubleshooting) when they receive a signal, in these cases I use kill as well ...

Comment: Actually HUP means "HangUP" and is sent when you log-out - or "loose the line" with a dial-up or serial-line.  This will usually cause the command to terminate.  The command `nohup` is used to make a command continue even after you log-out and the HUP-signal is sent - eg `nohup gcc my_command.c >& log`.  **However** *daemons* usually respond to the HUP-signal by reloading their config-files and/or restarting...  But this may be because daemons are specifically disconnected from all terminals and thus will never normally get the HUP-signal, thus freeing HUP for use as "reload config" signal.

Comment: My .project file for root, used to be "Licensed to kill - processes".

Comment: please don't use signals numbers specific to Linux as some are different on other OS (e.g. BSD hence MacOS)

Comment: SIGSEGV can be intercepted. When the signal is sent by the kernel because of a genuine segmentation fault, it's hazardous to catch it. But when it's not sent by the kernel because of a segfault, the signal can be intercepted/ignored.

Answer (score 12):

Originally, the kill command/system call just killed a process. This was done by the kernel and the process just disappeared, never being notified about it.
That stopped around Third Edition, I think.
kill -9 says to send signal number 9 to a process. Unlike most (all? it depends) other signals, it can't be 'caught' by a process and handled in any way. A kinder way to stop a process is kill -15 (or kill -TERM) which tells the process it is being terminated, but gives it a chance to perform cleanup.

Use of kill -9 is a 'guaranteed' way to kill a process; if it's stuck, kill -15 might not always work. Hence, many people still use kill -9 as a 'first resort'.

The reason the 'ultimate' kill signal is number 9 is just the way they did it. There were at least another eight different signals at that time, and I guess the numbers were assigned by the person who programmed that part of the kernel (probably Ken Thompson). Some of the lower numbers are now largely historical, as they map onto hardware instructions and/or events in the PDP-11 hardware. And there are also many others *above* 9.

Note that the actual numbers have no levels or hierarchy in them; in no sense is signal 8 'less' than signal 9 or 'greater' than signal 7.

Comment: Why are we not using 1 or 2 or 3 etc.. we just using 9 always. Is there a stages in between?

Comment: @Athiri Those aren't "levels" or "stages" of kill power, they are [signal numbers](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/programming/linux_pgsignals.html)

Comment: I've added an expanded explanation of signal numbers.

Comment: Of course the process is notified: if it wants to, it can set up a signal handler and catch the signal. If it wants not to die, it can do so. It's only *by default* that most signals kill the process. But SIGKILL (9) cannot be caught or ignored, which is why people think that `kill -9` is necessary: it is not - it depends on what you want to do (and BTW, if the process is sleeping uninterruptibly in the kernel, it cannot be killed: it will only disappear after a reboot). Also *all* of the "hardware" signals can be generated on modern hardware: which ones do you think are obsolete?

Comment: That's what I said: 

    `kill -9 says to send signal number 9 to a process. Unlike most (all? it depends) other signals, it can't be 'caught' by a process.`

I was thinking of SIGEMT and SIGBUS, which are not relevant to much modern hardware. Of course, other hardware events might be mapped onto them.

Comment: When I said the process was never notified, I said 'originally'. I was referring to very early UNIX, Third Edition or earlier.

Comment: SIGSTOP is the other signal which can not be caught.

Comment: Rereading your answer, I can see I missed a bunch of context. I have to read more carefully. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I do that too!

Answer (score 5):

Well... everyone's programming style is different, I suppose. Personally, I try to *avoid* sending a `kill -9` if I can because it tends to create zombie processes, as it does not allow the process it kills to execute *any* clean up actions that may or may not exist in the program the user wants to kill.

It is the 'last resort' signal, so while it's seldom the *preferred* way to terminate a program, it is commonly used, (particular in poorly written programs) because it "always works", so to speak...

If a process is ignoring `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`, than there *should* be a reason for that-- perhaps the process is supposed to release a lock file, delete some temporary file(s), and/or perform some other 'clean up' actions before termination. Of course, programs do misbehave, and thus we do need `SIGKILL` for those (hopefully rare) scenarios.

The only truly appropriate uses of  `SIGKILL` are when a process is misbehaving for some reason and thus will not properly terminate, or when the user needs to kill the process immediately for some other reason (for example, if you accidentally execute a trojan and than freak out, you may want to make sure that you kill the program quickly, and entirely).

The reason why you may see it often is because it is the only signal the kernel *cannot* ignore. In the shell you can play around with the `trap` command to see for yourself, but this a very good explanation of what `kill -9` does:

> **Signal 9 From Outer Space**
>
> There is one signal that you cannot trap: SIGKILL or signal 9. The
>   kernel immediately terminates any process sent this signal and no
>   signal handling is performed. Since it will always terminate a program
>   that is stuck, hung, or otherwise screwed up, it is tempting to think
>   that it's the easy way out when you have to get something to stop and
>   go away. Often you will see references to the following command which
>   sends the SIGKILL signal: kill -9
>
> However, despite its apparent ease, you must remember that when you
>   send this signal, no processing is done by the application. Often this
>   is OK, but with many programs it's not. In particular, many complex
>   programs (and some not-so-complex) create lock files to prevent
>   multiple copies of the program from running at the same time. When a
>   program that uses a lock file is sent a SIGKILL, it doesn't get the
>   chance to remove the lock file when it terminates. The presence of the
>   lock file will prevent the program from restarting until the lock file
>   is manually removed.
>
> Be warned. Use SIGKILL as a last resort.

[Source](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php)

Comment: fuser -ck  and kill -9 are does the same process?.

Answer (score 1):

I love this thread as it echoes back to the days I used to help my Dad on-site (during the early 80s) working on old Burroughs/Unisys systems... all the way to the present where **kill** has slightly evolved (for various reasons).

First, credit to @thecarpy and Bob for their responses.

Secondly, **kill** can take on different meanings based on the Unix/Unix-like system (or shell) implementation.  Originally, **kill** was a direct system call to module-based/monolithic-based kernels to allow a user to delete an active process from memory.  The point is, this command was a means for the kernel space (ring0), ring3 (user space), or higher-level users to destroy greedy/run-away processes from absorbing resources on old, main/mid-frame systems.

Third, the whole purpose of **kill** is to ensure a PID has a handle for SIGKILL to be sent -- per process/per terminal/per run-level.

With Unix-like systems, **kill -9** is used too frequently, IMHO, as it has been stated it can leave zombie processes.  This is due to the Parent->Child Process PID relationships based on forking, pipe-lining, and other reasons where the initial PID/Process spawns children, etc.

The command is quite useful as it is dangerous, but knowing the options (as mentioned above) and the PID in question (from a shell script to a core DB process) should be investigated first:

ps -aef | grep -i

Once identified, kill -15 was what I used to prevent zombies and run-away processes, such as in the early days of MySQL, to conserve system resources, however knowing the right SIGnal to send a process is important, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)

When in doubt, try to use the **pkill** command for named-processes, such as mariadb/httpd or kill -15 to immediately nuke a process.