# Run application if and only if SSH Tunneling is active on port X

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I am running a [code-server](https://github.com/coder/code-server) on my remote Ubuntu machine and right now my method for starting it up is to

1. `ssh -t -t user@server "code-server"` on one terminal (the `-t -t` I got from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210356))
2. `ssh -N -L 8443:127.0.0.1:8443 user@server` on a second terminal
3. Open the application on the browser

Then when I want to close it, I just close both terminals. My question is if would be possible to do this using only one connection, currently I have to authenticate twice because this requires two ssh sessions, one for starting the application and sending the KILL when closed and another one for the tunneling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the following and it seems to work:

```
ssh -t -t -L 8443:localhost:8443 user@server "sleep 3"

Connection to server closed.
```

it waits for 3 seconds and then closes the SSH session. I'd say you can put your application in the quotes instead of `sleep 3` or remove the whole `"sleep 3"` and that would give you interactive shell.

Comment: That works perfectly! I didn't realize I could just chain them together